# Is there a straightforward group homeomorphism between the 2-adic integers and $[0,1)$?

Tags: general-topology, functions, p-adic-number-theory, group-isomorphism

I think the (set of the) ring of 2-adic integers is represented by:

$$\left\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^ix_i:x_i\in\{0,1\}\right\}$$

And I think the set of real numbers in the interval $[0,1)$ is represented by:

$$\left\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^{-(i+1)}x_i:x_i\in\{0,1\}\right\}$$

Is it correct therefore, that there's a straightforward homeomorphism and order-isomorphism between the two given by reversal of the binary string?

Assuming that all checks out, does the homeomorphism extend to any other structures? e.g. It seems $[0,1)\cong\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is a group with addition modulo $1$.  But the obvious answer seems to be that addition doesn't correspond because carries go the opposite way.

Comment: The $2$-adic integers are totally disconnected, so there isn't a homoemorphism with $[0,1)$ in the usual topology or the $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ topology.

Comment: thanks @halrankard I don't doubt what you say, but are you able to give me a counterexample using the two representatives I've given, i.e. a sequence $x_i$ such that its 2-adic integer converges in the first set but for whom the same $x_i$ doesn't converge in the 2nd? Or a set $x_i$ that is in one but not the other?

Comment: @halrankard p.s. fwiw an issue I can see is the single point $0\cong1$ in $[0,1)$ where $0,0,0,\ldots=1,1,1,\ldots$ whereas in $\Bbb Z_2$ we have $0\neq -1$.  But maybe that is fixed by including $\{1\}$.

Comment: The map $\mathbb Z_2 \to [0,1]$ is not injective.  That is, some elements of $[0,1]$ have two different binary presentations.  For example $1/2 = .1\overline{0} = .0\overline{1}$.  Note that I included $1$ in $[0,1]$ because $\mathbb Z_2$ has an element with coefficients all $1$.

Comment: Thanks @GEdgar your first point was just beginning to dawn on me as I thought about $\overline1$. So to confirm, are we saying $[0,1]$ can be realised from $\Bbb Z_2$ using the quotient map that glues together equivalent binary fractions?

Comment: Yes! The map $\mathbb Z_2 \to [0,1]$ is continuous and surjective.  Both are compact Hausdorff spaces.  So this map is a quotient map for the topologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they're not homeomorphic because in $\Bbb R$ we have $0\overline{1}_2=1\overline0_2$ such as $0.\overline1_2=1$ whereas in $\Bbb Z_2$ we have $\overline1_2=-1\neq2^\infty=0$.  In fact $[0,1]$ can be realised from $\Bbb Z_2$ by applying the quotient map $\Bbb Z_2\to[0,1]$ that glues together equivalent binary fractions.